# How are boolean values treated in Excel?

Tags: excel, boolean, sumproduct, excel-365

I decided to learn how to work with the function `SumProduct()`, so I created this very basic Excel sheet:

```
A    B
1    1
2    2
```

I calculated `=SumProduct(A2:A3,B2:B3)` and the result was 5, which was as expected.

Then I got the idea to replace B2 by `=(1=1)`, which obviously is `TRUE`, which is confirmed by what I see.

However, the `=SumProduct()` result changed into 4, apparently `booleans` are treated as zero in Excel.
So, I decided to write another formula: `=A2*B2+A3*B3` (which is exactly the same as the `SumProduct()`), but instead of getting the expected value 4, the value remained 5.

So, apparently, regular mathematical operators (`*`, `+`, ...) treat `boolean` values as "to be expected" (`TRUE` becomes 1 and `FALSE` becomes 0), but for some more elaborated functions (like `SumProduct()`) this seems not to be the case.

What's the explanation behind this? I would like to understand what's happening in order to avoid unpleasant surprises. I think I'm working with Excel-365 (how can I be sure?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to this document: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/08/24/excel-sumproduct-function-formula-examples/

which explains that you need to prepend `--` before your value in order to convert it into the 1 or 0 you have expected. Thus, the function does not support boolean values, as you have correctly observed. You can also use an `IF` function whose first parameter is the logical expression that you have, the second parameter being 1 and the third being 0. As about the reason for the lack of support for implicit conversion of logical data into arithmetic data at this function, I think we will not be able to factually determine its reason at an online forum, but that is rather a question that you could direct to the authors of the function.

Comment: So basically you are saying "*Most Excel functions should handle booleans in a correct way, but `SumProduct()` is a known exception, for which the double negation trick can be used.*"?

Comment: That is why you'd mostly discard the 2nd parameter and write `=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A3*B2:B3)` @Dominique. The conversion of boolean to numeric is done in the 1st parameter in the same fashion as you wrote `=A2*B2+A3*B3`. Another example is `MMULT()` that will not handle boolean input. Good question though =)

Comment: @JvdV: your comment makes it really bizar: `=sumproduct(A2:A3,B2:B3)` means the same as `=sumproduct(A2:A3*B2:B3)`, but why would you want to write a multiplication (`*`) when you already mention a multiplication in your function (after all, the function is called Sum**Product**())? ... and in top of this, there seem to be cases where both are not equal anyway. (I have the strong impression that this function has not been tested very thouroughly :-) )

Comment: It's not that bizar IMHO. The function itself is not going to work through a hardcoded multiplication like `*` would. Just like `SUM(1,2,TRUE)` will still ignore the boolean values and return `3`. In that regard, `SUMPRODUCT()` does not stand alone. It needs *numeric* input. Whereas boolean values *can* be used in hardcoded calculations, they have no meaning to these functions on itself and will be discarded. Therefor we usually perform the hardcoded multiplication inside the 1st parameter. I hope that is more clear, as I'm not sure if what makes sense to me can come across that well =).

Comment: @Dominique there are multiple functions with this approach. `SUM` is another example, as JvdV pointed out. I agree with you that it would be good if boolean values could be implicitly converted into integers and, like you, I do not understand why didn't the authors choose this approach. However, what I **do** know is that this is not supported by some functions, `sumproduct` & co.